# How can I create a box for a combine of a figure and a table?

Tags: tables, boxes, tabularray

How can I create a box for a combine of a figure and a table?

```
\documentclass[paper=b5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\SomeNumbers
\sbox\SomeNumbers{\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines}1 & 2 & 3\end{tblr} \\
\vspace{1cm}
\includegraphics[]{example-image-a} }

\begin{document}
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l, h]X[l, h]} , hlines, vlines}
    {Fill \\ some \\ more \\ boxes} & \usebox\SomeNumbers
  \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

The code is adapted from [this](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/401).
This is the output of the code above:

[image]

However, I expect  the output should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: This gives a box with a figure and table (although you probably want a `width=` on your figure).  Is your question about having the table above the figure instead of in one line?

Comment: @Teepeemm that is true but it's more about creating a saving box so I can solve the issuse in the github link.

Comment: @Teepeemm did it work for you in solving the alignment issue in this case?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You have created a box.  It combines a figure and a table.  What is your specific request?

Comment: @Teepeemm I want to top align this text `{Fill \\ some \\ more \\ boxes}` and `\usebox\SomeNumbers` which is supposed to be a box with a table on top and a figure on the bottom. However, when I ran the code above, it  doesn't work as expected. If put only the table to the box then it works well. That is why I thought that there is some problem with creating a box of a figure and a table.

Comment: @Teepeemm I have just updated the post to show what I want to get.

Answer (score 2):

If you `\usebox\SomeNumbers` outside of the `tblr`, you'll see that you still get the undesired output.  The problem is that TeX is putting everything in horizontal mode.  We can fix this by putting the contents into a `\parbox` with the appropriate alignment.  (And the `\vspace` is happening too late, so you can switch that out for `\\[1cm]`.)  And despite the github issue, you can put the parbox into the `tlbr`.

```
\documentclass[paper=b5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\SomeNumbers
\sbox\SomeNumbers{\parbox[t]{2in}{\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines}1 & 2 & 3\end{tblr} \\[1cm]
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l, h]X[l, h]} , hlines, vlines}
    {Fill \\ some \\ more \\ boxes} & \usebox\SomeNumbers
  \end{tblr}
  
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l, h]X[l, h]} , hlines, vlines}
    {Fill \\ some \\ more \\ boxes} & 
    \parbox[t]{1.7in}{\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines}1 & 2 & 3\end{tblr} \\[1cm]
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}}
  \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]